# How to get devices name list in sender application using chrome-cast API

Tags: chromecast

I want to develop a sender application where I can get chrome cast devices name in drop down and on selection of devices we can map any url to selected device.

So Right now problem is that i am not getting any devices name using api. API don't have such method if anyone have any idea about this please help me out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presenting the list of device and allowing the user to select a particular device is done by the Cast extension in Chrome. The sender code cannot get the list of devices in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! Leon Nicholls
I want to know one more thing can we develop kind of sender application from where we cast multiple url in multiple devices which listed on chrome cast extension.
Means I select first url and lunch that url and select device to whom that lunched url we want to cast using extension, again we select second url and lunch and select another device which listed in extension same way we can develop ...???

Comment: Currently the Cast extension only supports connecting to one device at a time.

Comment: Thank you !!! 
Hi Leon Nicholls , I want to now any other alternative way to do such thing,Can I make something like this sender application which allow to us manage multiple device media ...

Comment: For a Chrome sender you cannot change the current behavior.